# T-SQL - Return right-most non-zero column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a strange scenario where I need to return the right-most non-zero column in a table structured as follows:

```
GL           Q1          Q2          Q3          Q4
1            100         0           0           0
2            100         900         250         0
3            600         100         0           1000
```

I am expecting the output to be:

```
GL           Amount
1            100
2            250
3            1000
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this as a set-based approach without having to resort to a CASE statement or similar solution?   Performance is going to be important here.

Comment: I don't suppose you can have those as null instead of 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT
   GL,
   COALESCE( NULLIF(Q4,0), NULLIF(Q3,0), NULLIF(Q2,0), NULLIF(Q1,0) ) as Amount
FROM
   myTable
```

Comment: @Jeremy -- thanks -- that's me paying attention.  :-)  fixed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no SET based approach, as SQL is designed to aggregate across rows, not columns.

I would actually expect CASE to be pretty fast here...

```
CASE WHEN Q4 <> 0 THEN Q4
     WHEN Q3 <> 0 THEN Q3
     WHEN Q2 <> 0 THEN Q2
     WHEN Q1 <> 0 THEN Q1
                  ELSE NULL
END
```

There is, however, an alternative using NULLs and COALESCE...

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Q4, 0), NULLIF(Q3, 0), NULLIF(Q2, 0), NULLIF(Q1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Case statement is correct to use here.  It is the most performant option available.

```
SELECT GL,
  CASE 
    WHEN Q4 != 0 THEN Q4
    WHEN Q3 != 0 THEN Q3
    WHEN Q2 != 0 THEN Q2
    ELSE Q1
  END
FROM TheTable
```

If you require a set based approach - you'd have to PIVOT and then aggregate by RowNumber.  That's slower.

Comment: ...and if you encounter nulls?

Comment: null behavior was not defined in the question... therefore not defined in the answer.

Comment: NULL is the default column specification on most RDBMS's.  If not specified, should be assumed.

Comment: @Jeremy: for SQL server (note tsql tag on the question) this is incorrect. NOT NULL is the default, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx Questions states "non-zero"

Comment: @Jeremy, I like to believe that those working with financial data have the sense to disallow nulls when they can.  null is not a valid quarterly earning amount.

Comment: Actually @gbn that's not the same thing.  Try it yourself, don't include a null specification on a `CREATE TABLE` query, and see for yourself you will end up with nullable columns.

Comment: @DavidB, as a dba and developer that works regularly with financials software, I can confidently state that "sense" does not enter into the picture.

Comment: What's this jibberjabber doing on my answer from over a year ago!

Comment: @DavidB hah I was just going through old stuff and saw responses that I wanted to clarify.  Sorry to bug you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(NULLIF(Q4,0),NULLIF(Q3,0),NULLIF(Q2,0),NULLIF(Q1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Set based-ish based on alpha sorting of "Q?" (Assumes not all quarters are 0)

```
with T as ( 
select GL, Q, VALUE, row_number() over (partition by GL order by Q desc) as row
    from (
        select GL,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4 from theTable
    ) T
    unpivot (VALUE for Q in (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4)) as U
    where VALUE <> 0 
)
select * from T
   where row = 1
```